# OpenXML SDK(C#): Copy all comments from one Excel workbook to another

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk, vba

I have one workbook which has data with comments - and I have the copy of the same workbook without comments.

I want to put all the comments in to second workbook. I tried appending comments from one file to another and it's not working.

Here is what I have tried so far...

```
SpreadsheetDocument docWithComments = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(@"...\Comments.xlsx", true);
SpreadsheetDocument docWithoutComments = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(@"...\NoComments.xlsx", true);
WorkbookPart wbpWithComments = docWithComments.WorkbookPart;
WorkbookPart wbpWithoutComments = docWithoutComments.WorkbookPart;

for (int i = 0; i < wbpWithComments.WorksheetParts.Count(); i++)
{
    if (wbpWithoutComments.WorksheetParts.ElementAt(i).WorksheetCommentsPart == null)
    {
        wbpWithoutComments.WorksheetParts.ElementAt(i).AddNewPart<WorksheetCommentsPart>();
        wbpWithoutComments.WorksheetParts.ElementAt(i).WorksheetCommentsPart.Comments = new Comments();
        wbpWithoutComments.WorksheetParts.ElementAt(i).WorksheetCommentsPart.Comments.CommentList = new CommentList();
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < wbpWithComments.WorksheetParts.ElementAt(i).WorksheetCommentsPart.Comments.Count(); j++)
    {
        var a = wbpWithComments.WorksheetParts.ElementAt(i).WorksheetCommentsPart.Comments.CommentList.ElementAt(j);
        wbpWithoutComments.WorksheetParts.ElementAt(i).WorksheetCommentsPart.Comments.CommentList.Append(a.CloneNode(true));
        var b = wbpWithoutComments.WorksheetParts.ElementAt(i).WorksheetCommentsPart.Comments.CommentList.ElementAt(j);
    }
}
```

This code is running without errors but the second workbook is not showing any comments.

Tell me if there is any better way available to complete this task? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: @Robin Mackenzie Thanks for the edit. Actually English is not my first language. I appreciate it. Thanks :)

Comment: No worries - its a good question - I only made some small edits :)